# reverted with panic code 50 when assigning uint256 to a uint256 memory dynamic array

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

```
    function getUserRewards(address staker)
    public
    view
    returns (uint256[] memory)
{
    Stake[] memory stakingHistory = tokenToOwnerToStake[s_stakingToken][
        staker
    ];
    uint256 len = stakingHistory.length;
    uint256[] memory rewards;
    for (uint i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        uint256 stakedAmount = stakingHistory[i].amount;
        uint256 stakedTimestamp = stakingHistory[i].timestamp;
        uint256 _reward = ((block.timestamp - stakedTimestamp) *
            rewardRate *
            stakedAmount) / totalStaked;
        console.log("reward %s i %s", _reward, i);
        rewards[0] = _reward; // possible issue here
    }
    return rewards;
}
```

results in

```
    reward 952371 i 0

      1) calculates reward correctly


  5 passing (971ms)
  1 failing

  1) Stakin
       stake
         calculates reward correctly:
     Error: call revert exception; VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with panic code 50 [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (method="getUserRewards(address)", data="0x4e487b710000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000032", errorArgs=[{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x32"}], errorName="Panic", errorSignature="Panic(uint256)", reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.7.0)
```

running on ^0.8.0

Comment: The array `rewards` is never initialized, you have to allocate memore before using it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the array needed to be initialized like this

```
    uint256[] memory rewards = new uint[](len);
```

Comment: Are you sure?  I'm learning Solidity and looking at https://solidity-by-example.org/app/multi-sig-wallet/ currently.  The owners array is never initialized with a size.  That's with solidity `0.8.20`